# If statement inside a JavaScript game not correctly executing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code and am trying to get the flappy bird to rise in the air which any part of the canvas is clicked.

I think I have placed the if statement wrong or there is some error with it.

```
 if(c.onclick="True"){
                birdDY==9;
            }
```

Could the error in this code be pointed out along with an explanation for where it should go?

**Whole code:**

```html
    <style>
    #block{
        width: 50px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: greenyellow;
        position: relative;
        left: 400px;
        animation: block 2s infinite linear;
    }
    @keyframes block{
        0%{left:400px}
        100%{left:-50px}
    }
    #hole{
        width: 50px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
        left: 400px;
        top: -500px;
        animation: block 2s infinite linear;
    }
    </style>
     <body style="height: 100vh; background: #111; text-align: center;">
      <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      
      <div id="block"></div>
              
      <script>
          
        //set up context
        context = c.getContext("2d");
        //create bird
        const bird = new Image();
        bird.src = "bird.png";
        //create variables
        var canvasSize = 400;
        var birdSize=30;
        var birdX = 0;
        var birdY =200;
        var birdDY = 0;
          
        var score = 0;
        var bestScore=0;
        var interval = 30; //the speed at which the game is played
        
        c.onclick = () => (birdDY = 9) ;
        
          
          setInterval(() => {
          context.fillStyle = "skyblue";
          context.fillRect(0,0,canvasSize,canvasSize); // Draw sky
          birdY -= birdDY -= 0.5; // Gravity
          context.drawImage(bird, birdX, birdY, birdSize, birdSize); // Draw bird (multiply the birdSize by a number to adjust size)
          context.fillStyle = "black";
          context.fillText(`Flappy Birds`, 170, 10); //x and y
          context.fillText(`Score: ${score++}`,350, 380); // Draw score
          context.fillStyle = "green";
          context.fillRect(300,20,canvasSize,canvasSize); // Draw blocks
           
        }, interval)
      </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: `=` is for assigning values, `==` and `===` are for comparing values.

Comment: The comparisson operator is "==", try: if(c.onclick == "True"){}

Comment: The return values of event listeners can't be catched, just set `birdDY=9;` inside the click handler.

Comment: could one or all of you please put this in a solution/answer and I will verify/accept.

Comment: What is yor goal for the `if`? As it is, it doesn't make any sense, are you expecting `c.onclick` to become `true` after a user has clicked on the canvas?

Comment: and just changing the = to == doesn't fix it.

Comment: @Teemu - the goal, as explained in the question, is for the flappy bird to go UP everytime the user clicks the screen.

Comment: Yes, but how is that `if` related to the goal?

Comment: if you have an answer please post it :)

Comment: this works - c.onclick = () => (birdDY = 9) ;     but I want to re-write that in a simple way for beginners (using a simple function)

Comment: `if` statement is not a function, the `onclick` is already the simplest possible way to do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not approaching the problem correctly.

First, `=` is used to ***assign*** a value, not test it. To ***compare** values, use `==` or `===`. In your case, you are setting `onclick` to "True", which itself can be evaluated as a "truthy" statement, so you would always execute the `true` branch of the `if`.

Next, in JavaScript, `true` is how you reference the Boolean `true` value. "True" is a string.

**But, `onclick` is a property and you shouldn't be testing it for `true` in the first place.** Your code is set to run immediately, instead you should be setting up an "event handling function (event handler) that will run when the element gets clicked. To do this use, [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) as in the following

```js
// Get a reference to the DOM element
const button = document.querySelector("button");

// Set up the event handler
button.addEventListener("click", doStuff);

// Define the event handling callback function
function doStuff(event){
  console.log("You clicked the button.");
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

In your case, that would mean your code would look like:

```
c.addEventLIstener("click", function(){
  birdDY = 9; }
);
```

Comment: useful, thank you - but can you post a solution so that my bird jumps on click. I am aware I've approached it wrong and am trying ...

Comment: @Compoot I really have, just replace the `button` in my example, with your reference to your `bird` element.

Comment: this works: c.onclick = () => (birdDY = 9) ;

Comment: I want to rewrite the above in a simple way using a function...I did not downvote you btw!

Comment: @Compoot You really shouldn't be using `onclick`, which is an event property. Instead, use `.addEventListener()`, but beyond that you'll have to be more specific as to what you hope to really be testing with your `if` statement since you're setting `birdDY to 9`. Why would you want to test it for `"True"`?

Comment: i don't want or need the true. I was merely trying to re-write this: c.onclick = () => (birdDY = 9) ;   .....what is a simple way of rewriting that such that it works (if you could add to your answer)

Comment: `c.addEventLIstener("click", function(){ birdDY = 9; });`

Comment: thanks. Replace my if statement with what you've suggested and nothing works. (you can replicate it). Replace it with c.onclick = () => (birdDY = 9) ;  and it works fine (bird jumps). How do I re-write that without the =() => in the traditional way - I suppose that would answer the question

Comment: @Compoot You say that your code works with what you have, but when I try it, I get tons of errors immediately.

Comment: forget the rendering of the blocks. I am only interested in making the bird jump. the exact code above works fine for me, with c.onclick = () => (birdDY = 9) ;

Comment: @Compoot I've already answered your question and I cannot ignore the multiple errors your code throws as is. I'm telling you `c.addEventLIstener("click", function(){ birdDY = 9; });` is a direct replacement for the more shorthand "arrow function" syntax you currently have. If it's not working, there is (likely) another problem.

Comment: thanks for trying - it doesn't work

Comment: @Compoot Yes, you've said that a number of times. And I've said a number of times that the code you've shared with us doesn't work at all in the first place (using the code that you keep saying does work). It throws all kinds of errors immediately. So, the fact that using my code doesn't work just means that you have other problems to solve.

Comment: @Compoot I've edited your question so that the code you posted can be run (using the code you say works) and as you can see, it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Scott - I see the question is now closed, but I've accepted your answer  - most helpful, thanks. I see what you mean now and I think I have it.

Answer (score -3):

try

```js
 if(c.onclick=="True"){
        birdDY=9;
  } 
// or try

 if(c.onclick===true){
        birdDY=9;
  }
```

#### Reference

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: thank you - but this doesn't work. See updated answer

Comment: This only addresses the `=` vs. `==` and `"True"` vs. `true` issue. It doesn't address that the event handler is being set up incorrectly in the first place.

Comment: At first look, anyone can tell that **if** statement is not used correctly. Anyone should first try by fixing this issue.

Comment: I am busy, so i can't figure out the code until **if** statement fixed.

Comment: The **If** statement is the basic building block of any programming language, and one should not miss use it.

Comment: I've updated the question - that is now ==  ...that's not the issue.